# empty SUM() with dynamic value

Tags: php, mysql

If I replace the first %s with just 244, I get the sum without any problems. But when using a dynamic value in this case $shot, it doesn't seem to get anything and neither my query fails as other results are fine (e.g. stories.id, stories.title).

```
$query = sprintf("
SELECT 
stories.id, 
stories.title,  
stories.timestamp, 
stories.text, 
users.name, 
users.avatar, 
users.id AS idus,
(SELECT sum(reviews.amount) FROM reviews WHERE reviews.storyid='%s') AS reviews 

FROM stories INNER JOIN users ON stories.uid=users.id WHERE stories.id = '%s'",
    mysql_real_escape_string($shot),
    mysql_real_escape_string($shot));
```

Shot is coming from here:

```
$shot = $_GET['shot'];
```

Comment: So are you escaping the string twice?

Comment: what is `$shot`?  What does it say when you `var_dump` it?

Comment: Is story id really considered a string? If it should be numeric, try without the `'`s and validate the `GET` variable as an integer.

Comment: string(3) "224" <= var_dump

Comment: Yeah those single quotes `'` look sketchy to me too.

Comment: Okay, now try `var_dump($query)` and see what exactly the query string is being generated as? Also, the ID doesn't look like it should be in single quotes as it appears to be an integer. You should validate it first as an integer, then put it into your query (`mysql_real_escape_string` shouldn't be necessary either).

Comment: string(290) " SELECT stories.id, stories.title, stories.timestamp, stories.text, users.name, users.avatar, users.id AS idus, (SELECT sum(reviews.amount) FROM reviews WHERE reviews.storyid='224') AS reviews FROM stories INNER JOIN users ON stories.uid=users.id WHERE stories.id='224'"

Comment: Have you tried it without the `'` in the query string?

Comment: Output from your dump = 224. Your test value in the question above = 244. Do you really expect them to yield the same result? ;)

Comment: Exactly that's the answer on the question. Thanks!

Comment: what PHP version u have? actually `mysql_*` has been removed in latest PHP. must use `mysqli_*`

Comment: be careful when using mysql_real_scape_string() ... https://www.owasp.org/index.php/PHP_Security_Cheat_Sheet#Escaping_is_not_safe

Comment: No problem! It may be a rookie mistake, but it's still easy to make... If your output doesn't match your expectations, check your input! Happy coding!

Answer (score 1):

I would write something like this.

```
SELECT 
stories.id, 
stories.title,  
stories.timestamp, 
stories.text, 
users.name, 
users.avatar, 
users.id AS idus,
SUM(reviews.amount) as reviews
FROM stories 
INNER JOIN users ON stories.uid=users.id 
INNER JOIN reviews ON stories.id = reviews.storyid
WHERE stories.id = '%s'"
```

*This has nothing to do with your question but a lot to do with Optimization.*

Answer (score 0):

Given that the id is always numeric,

Make `$shot = (int)$_GET['shot'];` (the %d specifier treats the variable as an integer, but you might need it somewhere else).

Then replace:

`reviews.storyid='%s'` with `reviews.storyid=%d`

and

`WHERE stories.id = '%s'`with `WHERE stories.id = %d`

No need to do `mysql_real_escape_string` ([why?](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php)).

Comment: I think there is no need to sanitize the input twice , first with typecasting `(int)` and then `%d`. you can use one of the above and that will be enough.

Comment: If `$shot` is needed anywhere else in the code, it's good to cast it into the correct type, I think.

Comment: Yes, using `%d` is far secure ...no need to type cast before forming the query using `(int)`

Answer (score 0):

Before executing your query, print it using

```
echo $query;
```

and see what is the outcome, if it isnt like when you put manual value than you need to change it.

I suggest using.

```
$shot = mysql_real_escape_string($shot);
$query = "SELECT 
stories.id, 
stories.title,  
stories.timestamp, 
stories.text, 
users.name, 
users.avatar, 
users.id AS idus,
(SELECT sum(reviews.amount) FROM reviews WHERE reviews.storyid='" . $shot . "') AS reviews 

FROM stories INNER JOIN users ON stories.uid=users.id WHERE stories.id = '" . $shot . "'";
```